# How to copy columns one after the other and perform calculations in between each copying?

Tags: excel, vba

I would be greatly obliged if someone could help me with the following.

I have 1300 columns of data (each column represents stock prices), some of them are up to 375 data points and others but most is less than 375 cells of data (or months if you like).

I need to copy column A from `Data` to `Sheet3` `Range("B2")`, which will then initiate already pre-defined formula in `Range("E6")` to calculate some values. Then I want the `Sheet3.Range("E6")` to be copied to the bottom of the `Sheet3.Range("I:I)`. Then I need to repeat the same operation but this time take the column B and do the same (and like this for 1300 columns from Data sheet).

I started working on some code but no success. Please advise. Thanks

```
Sub CopyCols()
    Const NUM_TIMES As Long = 10
    Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet, shtData As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range, i As Long

    Set Sheet3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set shtData = Sheets("Data")
    Set rngCopy = shtData.Range("A1:A375")

    For i = 1 To NUM_TIMES
        With Sheet3
            .Range("B2").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rngCopy.Value
            .Range("E5").Copy
            .Range("I1:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Calculate
            'rngCopy(1).Offset(17, 0).Resize(8, 1).Value = .Range("P12:P19").Value
        End With
        'Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(0, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue in the code is `Set rngCopy = shtData.Range("A1:A375")` is left out of the loop.

Code restructured and tested as far my understanding

```
Sub CopyCols()
Const NUM_TIMES As Long = 1300
Dim Sht3 As Worksheet, shtData As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range, i As Long
'Dim Arr As Variant
Dim tm As Double

tm = Timer
Set Sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set shtData = Sheets("Data")
Set rngCopy = shtData.Range("A1:A375")

    For i = 1 To NUM_TIMES
    Set rngCopy = shtData.Range(shtData.Cells(1, i), shtData.Cells(375, i))
    With Sht3
    .Range("B2").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rngCopy.Value
    .Calculate
    .Range("I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("E6").Value
    End With
    Next i
Debug.Print "Seconds taken" & Timer - tm
End Sub
```

`Sheet3` name  changed to `Sht3` as name `Sheet3` may contradict with code name of existing sheets in the workbook. Up to 375 rows are copied (make it the maximum possible in real case. It is better option than calculating last row and copying the same, it would call for additional requirement of clearing previous column data from `Sheet3` column B. This would make performance slower.

Comment: Ahmad, perfect. Thx bro